# I'm getting the error in accessing angular datatable angular.js:13550Error: [$injector:unpr] . I have provided the controller below:

Tags: javascript, angularjs

> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/unpr?p0=DTOptionsBuilderProvider%20%3C-%20DTOptionsBuilder%20%3C-%20playbackController
>       at n (http://localhost:63721/Scripts/angular.min.js:64:374)

I'm trying to make angularjs datatable but it is showing the above error

```
 myApp.controller('playController',['DTOptionsBuilder','DTColumnBuilder', function (DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {

        this.standardOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
            .fromSource('Scripts/datatables.standard.json')
             // Add Bootstrap compatibility
            .withDOM("<'dt-toolbar'<'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'f><'col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hidden-xs'l>r>" +
                "t" +
                "<'dt-toolbar-footer'<'col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hidden-xs'i><'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'p>>")
            .withBootstrap();
        this.standardColumns = [
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withClass('text-danger'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('name'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('phone'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('company'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('zip'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('city'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('date')
        ];

    }]);
```

Comment: buddy, you are missing DTOptionsBuilder in your project according to the error log. So, i prefer you to first see how to use service or factory into your angular project.

Answer (score 0):

`DTOptionsBuilder` can not be injected, because it is not defined beforehand. You need to either create a service, a controller or any other component with this name or add a missing library to your project. Otherwise it is not possible to inject the `DTOptionsBuilder` at that place.

Edit: I guess you are trying to run angular-datatables? If that is true, make sure you added the library to your HTML (`<script>` tags) and then add the library to your angular bootstrap array.

```
angular.module('myModule', ['datatables']);
```

Here is the link to the docs: [Getting started](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/gettingStarted).

Comment: I'm newbee to angularjs. .please explain me what should i do in DTOptionsBuilder  service.

Comment: If i add "angular.module('myModule', ['datatables']);" then i get this error    angular.js:13550TypeError: DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource(...).withDOM(...).withBootstrap is not a function

Comment: Okay, you have fixed your first error. The next one means, that the function `.withDom()` does not return an object with the function `withBootstrap()`. So go to the docs and find out how you can achieve what you want.

Comment: I checked and i got " Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined" in angular